# how can I abort a funciton after elapsed time?

Tags: c++, timer, clock, kill, abort

I am testing some algorithms and timing them. I would like to know how to abort the function while its running if it runs for longer than 60 seconds. Here's what I'm working with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isUnique(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) return true;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start, end - 1))
        return false;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start + 1, end))
        return false;
    return (arr[start] != arr[end]);
}

bool isUniqueLoop(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) return true;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= end; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])return false;
    return true;
}

bool isUniqueSort(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start <= end) return true;
    vector<int> buf(arr);
    sort(buf.begin() + start, buf.begin() + end);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        if (buf[i] == buf[i + 1]) return false;
    return true;
}

int main() {

        int max = 0;
        cout << "Enter a number for the Max range: ";
        cin >> max;
        default_random_engine randGen(time(0));
        uniform_int_distribution<int> randNum(0, max);
        int i;
        int j;
        int n = randNum(randGen);
        int m = n;

        vector<int> myVect;

        for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            myVect.push_back(randNum(randGen));
            //cout << myVect[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "Recursive Algorithm Test... " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        // recursive algorithm
            clock_t start = clock();
        isUnique(myVect, 0, n);
            if (isUnique(myVect, 0, n) == true) { 
            cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << endl;
        }
        clock_t end = clock();
        double time = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        cout << "CPU Time used for this algorithm: " << time << " ms" << endl;

        if (time > 60000) {
        cout << "This function takes too long! " << endl;
                }

        cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;


        cout << "Iterative Algorithm Test... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        // iterative algorithm
        clock_t start2 = clock();
        isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n);
        if (isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n) == true) {
            cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << endl;
        }
        clock_t end2 = clock();
        double time2 = (double)(end2 - start2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time2 << " ms. " << endl;
        if (time2 > 60000) {
            cout << "This function takes too long! " << endl;
        }
        cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;


        cout << "Sort Algorithm Test... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        // sort algorithm
        clock_t start3 = clock();
        isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n);
        if (isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n) == true) {
            cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Vector is not Unique " << endl;
        }
        clock_t end3 = clock();
        double time3 = (double)(end3 - start3) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time3 << " ms. " << endl;
        if (time3 > 60000) {
            cout << "This function takes too long! " << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

everything works fine except the fact that I want it to quit the function isUnique(myVect, 0, m) if it lasts longer than 60 seconds....Any suggestions?

Comment: If you run it in another thread then you could kill the thread but if it is in the same thread then the function has to detect how long it has been running exit itself after the required timeout.

Comment: I haven't learned anything about threads yet so I'm not sure what you're talking about. I know the function has to detect how long its been running, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an exceptional circumstance (like a timeout) you can throw an exception.  In your case what kind of exceptions is up to you.  Exceptions work well when you want to exit a many levels deep call tree without having to check every function individually for an exit return code.  In the example below I am throwing a string as an exception:

## Edit

To prevent doing the time calculations way too often here is an attempt to limit how often they are done.  This is by no means scientific, but on my box it gives a reasonable result.  If you have a better way let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

bool isUnique(const std::vector<int>& arr, int start, int end, clock_t clock_start,
              unsigned long & iterations, unsigned long timecheck) {

    if (++iterations > timecheck) {
        iterations = 0;
        clock_t clock_current = clock();
        double time = (double)(clock_current - clock_start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        if (time > 60000) throw "This function takes too long!";
        else std::cout << time << " ms elapsed..." << std::endl;
    }

    if (start >= end) return true;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start, end - 1, clock_start, iterations, timecheck))
        return false;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start + 1, end, clock_start, iterations, timecheck))
        return false;
    return (arr[start] != arr[end]);
}

bool isUniqueLoop(const std::vector<int>& arr, int start, int end, clock_t clock_start,
                  unsigned long & iterations, unsigned long timecheck) {

    if (start >= end) return true;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= end; j++) {

            if (++iterations > timecheck) {
                iterations = 0;
                clock_t clock_current = clock();
                double time = (double)(clock_current - clock_start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                if (time > 60000) throw "This function takes too long!";
                else std::cout << time << " ms elapsed..." << std::endl;
            }

            if (arr[i] == arr[j])return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool isUniqueSort(const std::vector<int>& arr, int start, int end, clock_t clock_start,
                  unsigned long & iterations, unsigned long timecheck) {

    if (start <= end) return true;
    std::vector<int> buf(arr);
    sort(buf.begin() + start, buf.begin() + end);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

        if (++iterations > timecheck) {
            iterations = 0;
            clock_t clock_current = clock();
            double time = (double)(clock_current - clock_start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            if (time > 60000) throw "This function takes too long!";
            else std::cout << time << " ms elapsed..." << std::endl;
        }

        if (buf[i] == buf[i + 1]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

unsigned long calculate_timecheck() {
    // since we want to limit the functions to 60 seconds we need to check how
    // long they have been running but we don't want to do that all the time
    // so we should only check so often - here is an attemopt to figure out how often

    unsigned long upperlimit = 1;
    volatile unsigned long i;
    clock_t start, current;
    double time;

    do {
        if (upperlimit > ULONG_MAX/2) return ULONG_MAX-1;
        upperlimit *= 2;
        start = clock();
        for (i = 0; i < upperlimit*100000; i++);
        current = clock();
        time = (double)(current - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << upperlimit*100000 << " iterations took " << time << " ms." << std::endl;
    } while (time<500);

    return upperlimit*100000;
}

int main() {

    int max = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter a number for the Max range: ";
    std::cin >> max;
    std::default_random_engine randGen(time(0));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randNum(0, max);
    int n = randNum(randGen);
    int m = n;

    std::vector<int> myVect;

    for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        myVect.push_back(randNum(randGen));
        //std::cout << myVect[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Calculating timeout... " << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    unsigned long timecheck = calculate_timecheck();
    std::cout << "Will check for timeout every " << timecheck << " iterations..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    // recursive algorithm
    try {
        std::cout << "Recursive Algorithm Test... " << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        clock_t start = clock();
        unsigned long iterations = 0;
        // isUnique(myVect, 0, n, start, iterations, timecheck);
        if (isUnique(myVect, 0, n, start, iterations, timecheck) == true) {
            std::cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << std::endl;
        }

        clock_t end = clock();
        double time = (double)(end - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "CPU Time used for this algorithm: " << time << " ms." << std::endl;
    } catch (const char *err) {
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    // iterative algorithm
    try {
        std::cout << "Iterative Algorithm Test... " << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        clock_t start = clock();
        unsigned long iterations = 0;
        // isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n, start, iterations, timecheck);
        if (isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n, start, iterations, timecheck) == true) {
            std::cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << std::endl;
        }

        clock_t end = clock();
        double time = (double)(end - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time << " ms." << std::endl;
    } catch (const char *err) {
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    // sort algorithm
    try {
        std::cout << "Sort Algorithm Test... " << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        clock_t start = clock();
        unsigned long iterations = 0;
        // isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n, start, iterations, timecheck);
        if (isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n, start, iterations, timecheck) == true) {
            std::cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "The Vector is not Unique " << std::endl;
        }

        clock_t end = clock();
        double time = (double)(end - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        std::cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time << " ms." << std::endl;
    } catch (const char *err) {
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

## Original:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isUnique(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end, clock_t clock_start) {

    clock_t clock_current = clock();
    double time = (double)(clock_current - clock_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
    if (time > 60000) throw "This function takes too long!";

    if (start >= end) return true;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start, end - 1, clock_start))
        return false;
    if (!isUnique(arr, start + 1, end, clock_start))
        return false;
    return (arr[start] != arr[end]);
}

bool isUniqueLoop(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end, clock_t clock_start) {
    if (start >= end) return true;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= end; j++) {

            clock_t clock_current = clock();
            double time = (double)(clock_current - clock_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
            if (time > 60000) throw "This function takes too long!";

            if (arr[i] == arr[j])return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool isUniqueSort(const vector<int>& arr, int start, int end, clock_t clock_start) {
    if (start <= end) return true;
    vector<int> buf(arr);
    sort(buf.begin() + start, buf.begin() + end);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

        clock_t clock_current = clock();
        double time = (double)(clock_current - clock_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        if (time > 60000) throw "This function takes too long!";

        if (buf[i] == buf[i + 1]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {

    int max = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number for the Max range: ";
    cin >> max;
    default_random_engine randGen(time(0));
    uniform_int_distribution<int> randNum(0, max);
    int i;
    int j;
    int n = randNum(randGen);
    int m = n;

    vector<int> myVect;

    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        myVect.push_back(randNum(randGen));
        //cout << myVect[i] << endl;
    }

    try {
        cout << "Recursive Algorithm Test... " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        // recursive algorithm
        clock_t start = clock();
        isUnique(myVect, 0, n, start);
        if (isUnique(myVect, 0, n, start) == true) {
            cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << endl;
        }

        clock_t end = clock();
        double time = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        cout << "CPU Time used for this algorithm: " << time << " ms" << endl;
    } catch (const char *err) {
        cout << err << endl;
    }

    cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;

    try {
        cout << "Iterative Algorithm Test... " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        // iterative algorithm
        clock_t start2 = clock();
        isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n, start2);
        if (isUniqueLoop(myVect, 0, n, start2) == true) {
            cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Vector is not Unique! " << endl;
        }

        clock_t end2 = clock();
        double time2 = (double)(end2 - start2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time2 << " ms. " << endl;
    } catch (const char *err) {
        cout << err << endl;
    }

    cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;

    try {
        cout << "Sort Algorithm Test... " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        // sort algorithm
        clock_t start3 = clock();
        isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n, start3);
        if (isUniqueSort(myVect, 0, n, start3) == true) {
            cout << "The Vector is Unique! " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "The Vector is not Unique " << endl;
        }

        clock_t end3 = clock();
        double time3 = (double)(end3 - start3) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
        cout << "CPU time used for this algorithm: " << time3 << " ms. " << endl;
    } catch (const char *err) {
        cout << err << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see what you did other than put the whole thing in a try block, and used a string. I am trying to stop the function after 60 seconds has elapsed. I need to know how to constantly time the isUnique function as it is running and stop it if it has been running for 60 seconds or longer.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see where you edited the actual function arguments and body. I'll give it a try and see what happens..no pun intended

Comment: @ElliotWerner  You have to pass in the start time so that you always know what it is - but the current time must be calculated in the function.  You could change the return type to something that can hold three values and return an "timed out" return value but then you have to check it everywhere - but that's what an exception was designed to deal with.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to do that. So I see that the start and end time is happening inside the function now, but the if statement where time > 60000 requires me to subtract end-start..in order to do that, it has to end first which, if it takes more than 60 seconds to end, then I still can't stop the function. I'm kind of confused.

Comment: This is the right basic idea. You might want to reduce the frequency of the checks though because all the clock math is going to vastly exceed the cost of the sorting/iterating/whatever. @ElliotWerner why are you doing this, anyway? Perhaps we can suggest something less intensive.

Comment: @user4581301 That's true - the timing code is going to be the slow part.  But it isn't clear to me how often he needs to do this.  For example, in isUniqueSort() do you check it every million iterations or every thousand?  It depends on profiling the speed of the end user's system.  On my RS6000 every 10 million iterations would still be too many but on my Arduino maybe 100 is the right number.  How fast is the end user's system anyway?

Comment: @user4581301 Maybe I will edit the answer to do a profiling loop to calculate iterations in two seconds and then use that that numer of iterations for the check.  It's a good idea.

Comment: If I had to do this, I'd have `std::async` run in the background, sleeping for 60 seconds, and setting an atomic flag (`std::atomic<bool>`, probably). The mainline of code would just test the flag and `throw` or `return`. Still like to know that problem Elliot is trying to solve. Very possible that the real solution is use a faster algorithm.

Comment: I like that whole idea.  If you had c++11 or better that would be the idiomatic way wouldn't it?

Comment: The three isUnique() functions that I am testing are out of my textbook for college and it is a project I am doing. Yes, I know the recursive one is ineffective, they made it that way on purpose and even stated it was ineffective. I need to test each one of them to find the largest value of n, such that each algorithm runs in one minute or less, which is why I am trying to halt it at one minute because if it runs longer than in a minute it has failed and I need to retest it.

Comment: I just want to know the easiest way to do it. I am looking at @JerryJeremiah edited code and I'm kind of confused. I know the times will vary anyway based on hardware. Technically my code still runs fine and does what it is supposed to do, testing wise, but I just want to add the timeout as an additional feature so the test doesn't run forever. For instance, sometimes I'll put the max range in as say 200 and the recursive will run in like 20ms, other times it'll take like 5 minutes and still not finish, so I end up closing the console.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I tested your edit on my system and for the max range input gave it a vector sized 1500. the recursive one did finally time out but after 2 minutes. I don't understand the code though because there is stuff going on there that I'm not used to seeing.